# Codeigniter: same global exception showing several times

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter & displaying global exception with the help of php by  extending Exception class

**Now the problem is:**  on the same page the exception message(see screenshot) is showing several times depending on the number of exception generated... i want to show only message to user at browser...

How can i make to show only one message in the browser ?

**Code from where exception message is generating**

```
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    } 

    function log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line) {

        if (ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {
            $to = "developer@example.com";
            $subject = "Fitness Trainer -Production Exception";
            $message = 'Severity: ' . $severity . '  --> ' . $message . ' ' . $filepath . '<br/> ' . $line;
            $from = "robot@gmail.com";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            echo '<div  style="width: 70%;text-align: left;margin-left: 15%;" class="alert alert-warning text-center alert-dismissible server-side-msg text-capitalize"   role="alert">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
                <strong>We apologize for the inconvenience,An exception occurred from our side and will work to resolve it....
                </strong>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            </div>';
        }  
        parent::log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
    } 
}?>
```

**Screenshot of Repeated  Message**
[image]

Comment: what about a try/catch ?

Comment: can you post the controller code from where its being generated @Sundara

Comment: are you calling `parent::log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);` right after having already echoed the error..?

Comment: Something calls `log_exception` multiple times.

Comment: @Sundara i think exactly the same like Ben Beri. it might be calling multiple times.

Comment: @Sundara We can't know without seeing the Behind the scenes code.\

Comment: @BenBeri Behind the scene code means , which?   Can we put some flag check in this class MY_Exceptions

Comment: Please show us what `parent::log_exception` does, and what calls `MY_Exceptions#log_exception`

Comment: @BenBeri Can we put some flag check in this class MY_Exceptions

Comment: @Sundara That'd be a very cheap solution, I think you should figure out what makes it print multiple times.

Comment: @Sundara What does log_message() do and where is it located at? Is it a functions included file?

Comment: in `CI_Exceptions`, put `echo 'test';` at the beginning, and run the script. If it prints 'test' 4 times aswell, then the problem is not in the parent class, but the part that calls `MY_Exceptions#log_exception`

Comment: we need a *minimal* example which reporduces the problem. there's just way too much code here. strip everything that's not relevant.

Comment: @BenBeri  Its printing only once the test message .. i kept  in CI_Exceptions,  echo 'test'; at the beginning,   As you said above

Comment: After `if (ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {`, can you add a test echo aswell and tell us how many times it prints?

Comment: @Sundara: it's a cycle. you remove unrelevant code, test, if the problem still occours - great. next cycle. keep repeating it. then post code.

Comment: Prints 4 times inside the if statement, yet prints once in the parent method. Something smells really fishy and confusing here. We definitely need to see the code that calls `log_exception` in `MY_Exceptions`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath  I removed extra codes... what does you are trying to suggest me with this ? " it's a cycle. you remove unrelevant code, test, if the problem still occours - great. next cycle. keep repeating it. then post code"

Comment: @BenBeri Ha ha ! that's why i thought to ask you Folks!

Comment: Question: Whenever it does log_exception, does it create a new instance of MY_Exceptions? or only calls log_exception? If it creates a new instance, you can't use a flag check.

Comment: @BenBeri i think new instance...

Comment: @Sundara Yeah then you have to show us what creates a new instance and where.

Comment: @BenBeri  i am going to try with jquery like going to show only one div on page load .. do you know how to do this with jquery